# How can we find the total number of tokens available in a wallet ? (withOut initialising Moralis) -As it is time taking

Tags: reactjs, moralis, web3-react, blockchain.info-api

```
const Moralis = require('moralis').default
const {EvmChain} = require('@moralisweb3/evm-utils')
const runApp = async () => {

// WithOut Moralis initialising  - I want to skip these ------(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4cGM.jpg)

    await Moralis.start({
        apiKey: 'api_key_secret'
    })

// ------------------

    const address = '0xbf820316675F3F96beb7a47Cec34c5aEdf07BD0e'
    const chain = EvmChain.GOERLI
   
    const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getWalletTokenBalances({
        address,
        chain
    })
    console.log(response.toJSON())
}
runApp()
```

As every detail of a `smartContract` is public. I don't want to use the API of a third party like Moralis as it slows the app.

Comment: The Moralis API should return a result within a few seconds. If you have problems with it, please post on https://forum.moralis.io. It would be a much more tedious process to query the ERC20 balances for an address against every possible token contract if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right all the smartContract data on the blockchain is public. But it is not always easy to read this data. To read data from the blockchain you would need to run your own local rpc node or you may have to rely on another 3rd node provider or API provider to read the blockchain data.

Moralis provides the data to users through the API and it is one of the fastest ways to read real-time blockchain data.

If you don't want to use any third-party providers for reading blockchain data, one option is to run your own full RPC node. This requires setting up a server and syncing the entire blockchain to your machine. It gives you the ability to read the data directly from the blockchain. This can be a good option if you have the technical expertise and the resources to set up and maintain a full node.

But this is not an easy option nor the fastest option to choose if you are only looking to get the ERC20 token wallet balances.